# Pandas Dataframe to Apache Beam PCollection conversion problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-beam

I'm trying to convert a pandas DataFrame to a PCollection from Apache Beam.
Unfortunately, when I use `to_pcollection()` function, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_expr'
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?
I'm using pandas=1.1.4, beam=2.25.0 and Python 3.6.9.

Comment: I get the same error with beam 2.25.0, pandas 1.1.3, and python 3.7.9 
```import apache_beam.dataframe.convert import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([1,2,3]
pc = apache_beam.dataframe.convert.to_pcollection(df)
```
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_expr'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_pcollection` was only ever intended to apply to Beam's deferred Dataframes, but looking at this it makes sense that it should work, and isn't obvious how to do manually.  https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/14170 should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem when I use a "native" Pandas dataframe instead of a dataframe created by `to_dataframe` within Beam. I suspect that the dataframe created by Beam wraps or subclasses a Pandas dataframe with new attributes (like `_expr`) that the native Pandas dataframe doesn't have.

The real answer involves knowing how to use `apache_beam.dataframe.convert.to_dataframe`, but I can't figure out how to set the proxy object correctly (I get Singleton errors when I try to later use `to_pcollection`). So since I can't get the "right" way to to work in 2.25.0 (I'm new to Beam and Pandas—and don't know how proxy objects work—so take all this with a grain of salt), I use this workaround:

```py
class SomeDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, pair): # pair is a key/value tuple
        df = pd.DataFrame(pair[1]) # just the array of values

        ## do something with the dataframe
        ...

        records = df.to_dict('records')

        # return a tuple with the same shape as the one we received
        return [(rec["key"], rec) for rec in records]
```

which I invoke with something like this:

```py
rows = (
    pcoll
    | beam.ParDo(SomeDoFn())
)
```

I hope others will give you a better answer than this workaround.

Comment: Thank you! The workaround does indeed work, even though I also still hope to get the answer to the problem :)